# Python code using panda library shows empty dataframe or results in error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image][image]

I am currently trying to automatically append data from one excel file to an already existing one which I use for Power BI analysis. To keep it a bit more simple, I've simplified my excel files.

The data in my source file looks like this (from column A to E):
292, 495, 68, 376, 1326

The destination file (which I use for Power BI) looks like this:
The first column has dates of the first day of the week. Each row contains the numbers from the data in my source file (which change every week).

I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

copy = pd.read_excel("Source_file.xlsx", sheet_name="Blad1")

with pd.ExcelWriter("Destination_file.xlsx", mode="a",engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    copy.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", header=None, index=False, startrow=writer.sheets["Sheet1"].max_row, startcol=1)
```

This gives me the following error:

How do I append data to the bottom of my destination file (see attached, marked red) when I already have the dates in place? (now all the appended data ends up at the rows that don't contain dates in the first column).

Answer (score 1):

I made some very minor fixes on your code and this one actually gives the expected ouptut :

```
import pandas as pd

copy = pd.read_excel("source_file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")

with pd.ExcelWriter("destination_file.xlsx", mode="a",
                    engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    copy.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", header=None, index=False,
                  startrow=writer.sheets["Sheet1"].max_row, startcol=1)
```

Ouptut :

[image]

Comment: **INSTALLED VERSIONS** : `pandas`  : 2.0.0, `openpyxl`  : 3.0.10.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick tips! I now understand the start column part, but I still end up with the following problem: In my destination file I already have the 'week starting' dates filled in (i.e. they are filled in up to row 10). The code than still appends the data on the 11th row. Is there a fix to this problem?

Comment: Can you share the code used and eventually some screenshots of both files ?

Comment: I updated the my initial thread with the screenshots and code.

Comment: The first ss does not show the column letters but can you try `startrow=len(writer.sheets["Sheet1"]["B"])` instead of `startrow=writer.sheets["Sheet1"].max_row` ?

Comment: When I change it to startrow=len(writer.sheets["Sheet1"]["1"]), instead of ["B"] it starts writing the data in the correct column. The only problem I have now is that whenever I append new data, it writes it to the same row repeatedly. (So it now only writes to the row that has the date '13-02-2023' in it)